# why the django PasswordResetView throwing error?

Tags: django

I have just starting to import the Django's password reset views in my urls, I have imported as below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
path('reset-password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView, name='reset_password'),
```

I tried to open the url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password/`

I get an error:

```
TypeError at /reset-password/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I mean I didn't even do anything extra and it is throwing the error. Nothing seems to be working for me. This is crazy.

> Django Version:   3.0.8

Any suggestions?
Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [**`.as_view()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) method while connecting the view in urls.

```
auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view()
```

hence the pattern looks like,

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('reset-password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),
]
```